# Is it ok to pass the entire Redux state object into a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

We have a component which needs access to Redux's store.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const Component = (props) => {
   ... code ...
}
```

We've connected this componet to the store using `connect`.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```

We now need to define `mapStateToProps` to pass as the first argument to `connect`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ ...state })
```

Why or why not is this an acceptable approach to injecting the data into the component? Would this make this component rerender in every situation that triggers a render?

Documentation and examples welcome.

[Demo Application](http://reduxabox.netlify.com)

FYI: I'm doing it for the second part of this [video](https://youtu.be/x2E9sG-bKlc) and considering listing it as the final solution. Would love to know Stack's thoughts on this code.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bad idea to pass the entire Redux state into a component.

**Although your component today  uses all the variables of the store, in the future it can be a different situation.**

Imagine that in the future you or other people create many new components that handle its vars in the store. You see? The first components would receive a lot unnecessarily data.

Comment: ...and then once you have "extra" state coming in as `props`, you'll get `PropType` errors everywhere and incur superfluous renders for updates to `props` that have nothing to do with your component.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Whilst you would get unnecessary re-renders, you wouldn't get `PropType` errors as proptype validation does not care about extra properties.

Answer (score -1):

It will only rerender on the props the component actually uses, React is smart like that. However, my personal preference is to not pass the entire object, it might be easier to code, but is a lot less verbose.

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ ...state })
```

In this line of code, you have no idea what the component is going to use, which makes your code way less readable, I also like to have control over the naming, that's why I prefer

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
  primary,                                    
  secondary,
  myComponentActive: active                                   
})
```

Now, when someone is reading your code, he knows exactly what's going on.

This also gives you a better overview if you ever want to change over to React Hooks, omitting the `mapStateToProps` object. Even though there is still discussion whether Hooks are the future, I find it be very convenient. That is not of much use for your video, although you might discuss the possibility of changing over!

Comment: "It will only rerender on the props the component actually uses" - This is not true. If you attach a property in `mapStateToProps` then it is "used" and when reconciliation occurs, react will see the component has a certain prop that has changed and will call a re-render. If it is a `PureComponent`, regardless of whether it is "used" or not, it will still compare it with the old value to determine whether a re-render is needed.

Comment: But if the component never actually uses it, then it will never change, hence no unnecessary renders.

Comment: @iqbal125 It can still be changed - Just not by the component (Not that the component could change it anyway, as its a `prop`)